ReactJS each child should have unique key
I have following code where i am using book.id to as key, but for some reason it does not work.
<h1>Book shop</h1>
        <div className="books">
            {books.map(book=>(
                <div className="book" key={book.id}>
                    {book.cover && <img src={book.cover} alt=""/>}
                    <h2>{book.title}</h2>
                    <p>{book.description}</p>
                    <span>{book.price}</span>
                    <button className="delete" onClick={()=>handleDelete(book.id)}>Delete</button>
                    <button className="update">Update</button>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>

The error i get is following (when doing inspect page in browser)
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Books`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at div
    at Books (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:377:76)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39894:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40596:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40530:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38471:5)
    at div
    at App

My code is written in React (front) and Nodejs (backend), and am having list of books containing several book entries which i am trying to update or delete, but then am getting 404 Not found message(because of not correct id?) (in my db it is book.id key) and am trying to see how can this be fixed. Thank you for reading, i am very appreciative if anyone has an idea why this happens.
(this below is how it looks in mysql, and ID is being auto incremented)
ID  title  description  cover  price
1   test title  description cover.png   123
2   title from backend  description cover from backend  100
3   title from backend2 description2    cover from backend2 221
4   title from backend2 description2    cover from backend2 103
5   asdfg title some description    coverrr 52
6   title123        cover2  3579
7   Titles      covered 50
                


Thank you for the comment, what do you mean to put index as key though? my key is book.id, not index, do you mean i should connect key,index and book.id somehow?

@AniketPandey using the index is as key is highly discouraged and should only be used if you have nothing else to use as a key.

@slomil there seems to be something wrong with book.id. You said that your requests to the backend also throw due to invalid ids. Check the data you get from the backend. My best guess is that the id is undefined or an object or that it is not id but $id or uid or something like that. Check the data.

The "error" you show is just a warning. You should fix it with other people answers but this warning is not preventing your component from rendering.


Ensure Uniqueness of book.id: Double-check your database and make sure that the id values for each book are unique
2.Use a Combination of Properties as key: If the id values are not unique, you can try using a combination of properties as the key.

Example

ChatGPT generated content is not allowed here,

Please provide your answer as a code block rather than a screenshot.

Looks like you are missing a bracket. This should work
<h1>Book shop</h1>
        <div className="books">
            {books.map((book)=>(
                <div className="book" key={book.id}>
                    {book.cover && <img src={book.cover} alt=""/>}
                    <h2>{book.title}</h2>
                    <p>{book.description}</p>
                    <span>{book.price}</span>
                    <button className="delete" onClick={()=>handleDelete(book.id)}>Delete</button>
                    <button className="update">Update</button>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>


Would be nice to say which brackets you added so other users doesn't have to compare each line to try to spot it. Brackets on arrow functions with one parameter are not mandatory, it's valid javascript code and does not throw errors or warning.
